# How can I get semantic word embneddings for compound terms?

Tags: machine-learning, word

I need to build semantic word embeddings representation of compound terms like "electronic engineer" or "microsoft excel". One approach would be to use a standard pretrained model an average the words but, since I have a corpus  of my domain, is there a possible better approach?

To be more precise:

The data I have is a corpus of millions of documents. Each document is ~ half a page and contains these compound terms. However there may be compound terms not included in the corpus.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an exact answer, please provide a precise question i.e. define what data you have, and what you exactly wants.

This said, in a general manner, you need a dataset of texts that contain these compound terms. How to treat compound terms is a whole scientific field in itself, but since you're talking about semantic word embeddings, I suggest you take a look at the article [Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases
and their Compositionality](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf). The same guys who introduced word2vec describe here a simple method to go from word representation to phrase representation, giving btw a way to merge compound terms in single terms. The words "microsoft excel" become "microsoft_excel" and get their own unique embedding.

If you want a python implementation for that, take a look at the [gensim.models.phrase](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) class. This does the same work as presented in the previous article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You already gave me what I wanted but I have made my answer more precise anyway.